# Help understanging ac signal connected to a charged capacitor (coupling capacitor)

Tags: capacitor, ac

(Assuming ideal elements) My friend is trying to convince me that the voltage across \$R_L\$ varies between 4 and 6, says the average value doesn't decrease and stays fixed at \$5V\$ forever. I'm not getting how this is possible -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXBVbJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The amplitude of the input ac signal varies between -1 and 1, always less than the capacitor voltage of \$5V\$. Wouldn't the capacitor see this low voltage and start discharging ? May I ask how the 1V input ac signal can put more charge into the capacitor so that the capacitor's voltage increases, even slighlty ? Makes not much sense to me. Highly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: What does "[4,6]" mean? Ditto elsewhere.

Comment: sorry it means any value between 4 and 6

Comment: The say that and don't use obscure references. Your friend is wrong BTW.

Comment: I'll update the post, thank you for letting me know :)

Comment: I thought so xD Initially, would the current stay positive till the capacitor discharges to 0V. Then somehow it has to follow the input voltage with 0 average value and lower amplitude ?

Comment: There is a DC path around the cap its going to discharge.

Comment: @sstobbe exactly! thank you :) would it discharge all the way to 0V ? I mean would the average value of voltage across the cap and RL reduce to 0V if we waited long enough ?

Comment: If you pull the cap out whatever DC value is present between Va and Vb is what the cap will (dis)charge to. I assume your signal gen has 0V offset, if so then yes steady-state DC is 0V.

Comment: In steady-state Vb always will always be 0VDC. Regardless if Va has a DC component or not.

Comment: @sstobbe That's because the capacitor charges to input signal DC offset and blocks further dc current reaching RL. I think I get steady state picture. Any thoughts about the initial response ? Would RL see more than 5V initially ?

Comment: Yes if you inserted a precharged cap to 5VDC, RL would see slightly less than 6V to slightly less than 4V. DC would decay as RC time constant to 0VDC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, There is a DC path around the cap its going to discharge. DC response follows RC time-constant.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Cool plot ! Definitely one picture is better than 1000 words! May I know which tool you're using ? @sstobbe

Comment: @Hiiii Its LTSpice http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/#LTspice It is Free!

Answer (score 2):

How about this, from Signal Wave Explorer: 1MHz DC-block (high pass filter),
with 10MHz sin input 1volt peakpeak with 2.5 volt offset

[image]

Comment: May you comment what is represented by two upper graphs?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the sinewave with the square wave and now the situation will look like this:

[image]

As you can see the capacitor will have a path for a discharge current to flow. And after some time the capacitor reach steady state and in steady state condition, the average capacitor current is \$0A\$ over a cycle (I_charge = -I_discharge).
[AC Circuit Having Only Capacitor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287394/ac-circuit-having-only-capacitor/287475#287475)

**EDIT**

In real amp life the situation will look like this:

[image]

At **DC** the **Cin** capacitor is charged to \$2.6V\$

**For positive half-cycle (+1V peak):**

As you can see \$5V\$ source provide \$3.5μA\$ of current, but the base current needed to be equal to \$9μA\$, 
so this additional current will have to come from the AC signal source.

And the **Cin** capacitor is discharging (**I_discharge = -5.5μA**)

As I show in the diagram.

**For Negative half-cycle:**

This time the base need only \$3μA\$, but our \$5V\$ bias source provides \$8.5μA\$.

This implies that our AC signal source needs to "sink" this excess current \$5.5μA\$.

And **Cin** this time is charging (**I_charge = +5.5μA**)

As you can see the average capacitor current is 0A over a cycle, hence the average (DC) voltage across capacitor stay unchanged (2.6V).

Comment: @Hiiii I update my answer, I hope it will help.