# Differential stage Av value with current sources

Tags: circuit-analysis, differential-amplifier, power-amplifier

Why all books told that Av differential of an differential input stage in power amp is very big? Ad = Rc/re, but if there are current sources in the emitter and collector circuit they will have too big impedance and division one big "Rc" to another big "re" will not give very big "Ad" value. Where is a trick?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a schematic? I can't imagine what the circuit you have in mind looks like.

Comment: Add a schematic of what you mean. Yes even if it is a trivial circuit. I see no current sources so there aren't any.

Comment: Zout of Emitter Follower of Zin/hFE becomes load of other side.

Comment: Zin/hFE - may you show that on pic.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the differential stage with asymmetric output, the load current can "swing" from:

\$0A\$  to \$I_{EE}\$

[image]

And the gain is

$$A_d = 0.5*R_C \approx \frac{R_C}{2r_e}$$

But by adding the current mirror we can "increase" the gain (the gain is now the same as it is for a symmetrical output). Because now the load current can swing from:

\$-I_{EE}\$ to \$+I_{EE}\$

[image]

And the gain is:

$$A_d = gm*R_L \approx \frac{R_L}{r_e}$$

In your audio amplifier the dif. stage the load resistance is equal to the input impedance of a VAS stage (Q6). Hence, the DC gain is "low" because \$r_\pi\$ is low and the Miller capacitance. http://www.ecircuitcenter.com/Circuits_Audio_Amp/Miller_Integrator/Miller_Integrator.htm

Comment: Can I increase the input resistance of VAS stage (Q6) using for example current source if the emitter of Q6?

Comment: How does T5 and T6 current mirror affect the input resistance of differential stage (between point A and ground)?

Comment: May I use the following equation for input resistance of my amplifier between point A and ground: Rin = 2*(betta+1)*re?

Comment: But why you want to increase the VAS stage input resistance? The diff. stage input resistance is (beta+1)*2re. And the current source (T5) at the tail of a diff amp. does not affect the Rin.

Comment: I think that increase resistance of Q6 stage will inrease the Av of input differential stage or it isn't so?

Comment: Good job you made to paint illustrations how the current goes in input stage. I'm trying to do so on my scheme and can't find whole path of signal from input to output through voltage sources when Q1 opened/Q2 closed and Q1 closed/Q2 opened. May you help me with that? Write paths from Q1 to Load and from load to Q2 when Q1 on/Q2 off and Q1 off/Q2 on.

Comment: But the input stage doesn't need to have "high" voltage gain due to the Q6 and the Miller capacitance. The input stage act like input voltage converter to the output current ( differential transconductance stage).  And tomorrow  I will draw the current path for your input stage.

Comment: I upload my version of paths. Gray (ground to minus of down voltage source) - Q1 off. Orange (positive of upper voltage source to ground) - Q1 on.

Comment: @MaxMil you diagram shows how a "signal flow" not the current. In NPN transistor the base current enters the base terminal and live it at the emitter Ie = Ib + Ic. And input signal "modulates" the Ib current in the "rhythm" of the input signal. And the base current "modulates" the collector current in the "rhythm" of an input signal. Notice the input signal current path https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/310471/help-understanging-ac-signal-connected-to-a-charged-capacitor-coupling-capacito/310496#310496

Answer (score 2):

You have mentioned the expression **Ad = Rc/re**.

Please note that this expression is (1) a very rough approximation for a common emitter amplifier with heavy negative feedback (due to re) and (2) does not apply for a diff. amplifier. Neither for a simple one (two or three transistors only) nor for the one shown by you.

This is because the resistance in the common emitter path (as seen from the left transistor of the diff. pair) is bypassed by the low-resistive input of the most right transistors emitter.

For a good understanding of the various gain expressions (common mode, single diff. mode, full diff. mode) you must know the working principle of the diff. pair.

---

**Detailed derivation** (for the diff. stage Q1, Q2, Q3 only).

**Assumption**: Unsymm. differential operation with Vin1=Vin and Vin2=0 [Q1 can be treated as an emitter follower loaded by the input resistance of Q2 in common base configuration].

Gain: Ad=Gain1*Gain2=A1*A2 with

A1=gm1*ro/(1+gm1*ro) with ro=re||(1/gm2).

If the dynamic resistance re is very large (re>>1/gm2) we can set ro=1/gm2.

A1=(gm1/gm2)/(1+gm1/gm2).

For identical operational points for Q1 and Q2 we have: gm1=gm2=gm and the gain is

A1=1/2.

Hence, with A2=gm*Rc (Rc=collector resistance) the total gain is

**Ad=0.5*gm*Rc** .

Comment: I disagree. The asymmetrical voltage gain with current mirror as an active plus the external load resistance is gm*Rc

Comment: If you disagree, you should identify an error in my calculation. Do you? Where is the error?

Comment: OK, I see you don't include the current mirror in your derivation. So, everything is correct.

Comment: Yes - however, in case of a current mirror the formula does not apply because one must ask: What is Rc? There is no Rc and we need another transistor for processing the current difference of the first diff. stage.

Comment: @LvW How the A1=gm1*ro/(1+gm1*ro) was derived? I can't understand that.

Comment: This the classical formula for an emitter follower (common collector), because the second stage is acting as a load for the first stage (output at the emitter node --hence emitter follower).

Answer (score 2):

*Why all books told that Av differential of an differential input stage in power amp is very big?*

I find "all books" a dangerous statement. It really depends on the input stage if it has a large **voltage** gain (Av). Also you're talking about Power amplifiers for **audio**, you should have mentioned that because audio is **low frequency**. There are also Power Amplifiers for **high frequency** applications. Many tricks we can do in audio cannot be done at these high frequencies.

In the schematic you show the first stage **by itself** actually does **not** have a large voltage gain! The voltage gain is roughly equal to the gm of the input pair transistors times the load at the collector.

Here that load is Q12 and Q19 which make a current mirror. It means the (differential) currents from Q1 and Q2 are added and this current ends up the collector of Q12. This collector is loaded by the base of Q6 which is a diode to ground and this is a **low impedance**. Note that the signal is still a **current**. If you would calculate the actual voltage gain up until the collector of Q12, that gain would be quite low.

The AC signal **current** appearing at the collector of Q12 will go into Q6 and will then be multiplied by beta, flow through the string of diodes.

At these diodes the signal is turned into a **voltage** again and current amplified (buffered) to the output.

Do note that this design has **negative feedback** using C2, R3 and R10. This feedback sets the total gain of the amplifier. For this to work properly the **open-loop** gain of the amplifier needs to be high enough. That's why we want high-gain stages.

As you can see, this design is not so easy, it is not actually **only** the first stage that determines the gain. This circuit is basically a voltage-to-current converter  -  current amplifier  -- active load  -- current buffer  with overall feedback.

Comment: Tell, when I build any circuit like this need I always do full small-signal analysis of that circuit to find equation for example for Av or I can estimate that value and use appropriate schematic that will give Av within suitable limitations?

Comment: Yes you need the full small-signal diagram and analysis of the circuit. With experience you recognize certain circuits and you will "see" the small signal behavior more easily without explicitly drawing it on paper. I'm experienced so I can do the latter. You're learning so you have to do the first.