# Gmo2 from vout about differential amplificator

Tags: current, amplifier, differential, transconductance, mirror

I'd like to know if this demostration is correct to calculate Gmo2 from vout about differential amplificator from this diagram :

[image]

### 1 : Gmo transconductance about Common Base configuration

[image]

[image]

[image]

### 2 : Gmo1 transconductance from T1

[image]

[image]

### 3 : Gmo2 transconductance from T2

[image]

[image]

[image]

with

### 4 : Rout from output (vo)

[image]

### 5 : Rin from ib1

[image]

[image]

[image]

### B11 : BAD diagram - Measure of vout with the half of gm

[image]

### B12 : Good diagram - Measure of vout with the half of gm

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuSKdV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

[Link](https://www.multisim.com/content/Sccu8WsWATThkrMLp3AgcX/ampli-diff-gm-sur-2/open/)

### B21 : Bad diagram Measure of vout with the all the gm

[image]

##### DC Op

[image]

### B22 : Good diagram - Measure of vout with the all the gm

[image]

[Link](https://www.multisim.com/content/hMXrRjZ78ME28JQbnj2CCE/ampli-diff-gm/open/)

Comment: Look here at a more intuitive approach to see why the voltage gain is equal to \$g_m \times R_L\$  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333502/differential-stage-av-value-with-current-sources/333536#333536

Comment: What answer do you expect from us?

Comment: I understood from the mentioned link that a transistor mounted as a diode makes the pair of transistor (current mirror) behave in all or nothing and there is in this case always a current ic flowing through Rload.

With diagrams B1 and B2 I have difficulty interpreting that in B1 we have half and that in B2 we have all the gm. In B2 for the DC current I always have ic of the transistor = io / 2.

Comment: If a understand the average of current in B1 is half vout so the  power measurement  will give the half. In B2 voltage and current give always the same curve  ...

Comment: You need to elaborate a bit more because I still do not understand what your question is about. Also, in your simulation, the BJT's are not properly biased. You need to add a negative voltage for a 3mA current source.

Comment: Thank you for your expertise! My demonstration is to show the increasing of gain (by 2) with current mirror. You give me an intuitive example, that confirm my demonstration. Know i try to see, understand and interpret the result on the gain with 2 examples : one without current mirror and another with it. I have added a negative voltage for the current source. Put 2 voltage source (one with 180° of phasing) and replace Rc with 2kOhms. I don't see by theses 2 examples how to interpret that i get the double gain with current mirror.

Comment: Try to check in the simulation for the same input voltage swing the load current. In the current mirror version, you should get almost two times the large current swing  (I_L) at the load resistance. Almost two times because the current mirror current gain is slightly less than one. Try to use Rc = 200R (Rc as load resistance, no external load) and RL = 200R in a current mirror version.

Comment: I have tried without success. I' ve post a new question about that [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/566962/how-to-see-benefit-effect-of-bjt-current-mirror-in-the-load)