# How to see benefit effect of BJT current mirror in the load?

Tags: current, bjt, mirror

I don't arrive to see benefit effect of BJT current mirror in the load.

I would get twice ic (ic1+ic2 = 3mA) with the same sources (both with phasing =0). But here I(RL) = -29µA.

[image]

[link](https://www.multisim.com/content/pm8vwc8JWVC287m3m9Mjo8/ampli-diff-gm/open/)

### Origin diagram :

[image]

### The VB(Q3)-REF1 is 0V :

[image]

### The VB(Q3)-REF1 is 52mV with V1 180° phasing :

[image]

### Replacing with RC

[image]

Comment: You're mixing up the bias curent (I1, 3 mA) and the **signal current** (the current **change** due to input voltage. Also you're applying a **common mode** input voltage  instead of a **differential** input voltage. Plot the voltage between the base of Q3 and the base of Q4. Is that a 26 mV sinewave?

Comment: My diagram comes from this origin (i added in my question). The origin shows the benefit in Av. To measure the voltage between the base of Q3 and the base of Q4 I've taken REF1 at VB(Q4) and linked it to VB(Q3). The VB(Q3)-REF1 is 0V. It is not a 26mv wave. With 180° phasing in V1 i get VB(Q3)-REF1 = 52mV and pick I(RL)=2.21mA. I have done a mistake : from the begening  I(RL) = -29µA (not 3/2 mA).

Comment: So, now remove the current mirror and place Rc = 220R and repeat the simulation for the same Vin. And now you will see that the peak value of a collector current is 2.61mA - Icq = 2.61mA - 1.5mA = 1.1mA, but with the current mirror the peak value was 2.21mA (twice the value )

Comment: Also, notice on your original diagram the IL = I1 - I2 and notice that ΔI2 = - ΔI1. When I1 increases by ΔI1 the T2 collector current I2 will decrease its value by the same amount ΔI1 = ΔI2. This is why I2 = - I1 thus, IL = I1 - I2 = I1 - (-I1) = 2I1. Do you see it?

Comment: @user7058377 I just dropped into this one. First off, do you realize that the combination of the diff-amp pair and the current mirror produces a ***transconductance*** (amps per volt) amplifier. This is ***not*** the same thing as simple unitless voltage gain. I see that you use a resistor to convert it back to a voltage (good idea.) But you can change the value of that resistor and get different voltage gains. In fact, you can change it a lot to get lots of different voltage gains. What you have to compare with is the case without the mirror and with two collector resistors.

Comment: @user7058377 Usually, a resistor is ***not*** used to convert this current into a voltage. You can do that. But that's not how this stage is usually followed. The current that is *squirting* out of the current mirror arrangement is usually fed into a VAS stage, which greatly amplifies the current but which perhaps more importantly also protects the collector voltage swing and mitigates the Early Effect, too. You need to use tools in the right way. But even so, it's still better than using collector resistors, even when you use it the wrong way.

Comment: @user7058377 Using an active load (current mirror) rather than a resistive load in a conventionally configured amplifier (Diff amp followed by VAS ) will double the transconductance of the input stage and double the slew rate.

Comment: @user7058377 .... In addition, using a current mirror will cause less 2nd harmonic distortion because a current mirror achieves a closer balance of the currents in the two sides of the differential amplifier compared to the poorer current balancing that can be achieved with a resistive load. The currents in the two sides of the input stage need to be well balanced to avoid higher distortion.