# M1 and M3 are connected in OTA, but in (a) they are separated. The author thinks they're equivalent. Why?

Tags: current-mirror

The following is from the book [*Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits*](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf), page 147.

M1 and M3 are connected in OTA (operational transconductance amplifier), but in (a) they are separated. The author thinks they're equivalent. Why?

How can this five transistor OTA circuit be converted to (a)?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No, the author doesn't think that these two circuits are equivalent.
He writes:

> We analyze a simpler topology with passive load before studying the
> OTA (fig 5.22)

The circuit shown in Fig. 5.23 is a diff amp with a current source as an active load. And the gain is Av = (gm*RL)/2. Because we do not use M1 current.

But if we use the current mirror as active load the voltage gain will increase to Av = gm*RL.

We have a similar situation in BJT's case.
[Differential stage Av value with current sources](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333502/differential-stage-av-value-with-current-sources/333536#333536)

Comment: Is the gain \$ \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in1} - V_{in2}}\$,  \$\frac{V_{out}} {V_{in1}}\$ or \$\mbox{ $\Large \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in2}}$ }\$?

Comment: Vout/(Vin1 - Vin2)