# Power amplifier input source current path

Tags: amplifier, bjt, analysis, small-signal

Can anyone draw (or write in text) the small-signal path from signal source XFG1 at input of Q1 base to amplifier load for positive and negative input signal swing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pretty much every point in the circuit not fixed to +32V, 0V or -32V.

Comment: Any amplifier is a "power supply" modulator. The input signal modulates the power supply current to create the input signal copy but with larger amplitude. Also, notice that in your amplifier the input stage and the VAS stage (Q6) work in class A. And the Output stage for low output power also work in class A. So it is not so easy to show how current flow. Also, what do you mean saying "small-signal path"?

Comment: Here you can find the example of an input current path for a CE amplifier. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/310471/help-understanging-ac-signal-connected-to-a-charged-capacitor-coupling-capacito/310496#310496 Is this is what you have looking for?

Comment: I mean that the signal that goes from XFG1 with positive sinusoidal swing will close the Q1 and the base of Q6 will see the inverted signal that will open it. Then current will be inverted and two upper output bjts will be opening and the amplified signal will go into the load. But what is for negative input signal swing, how it will move?

Comment: I also add how I see the DC voltage moving. Orange - Q1 is on, gray - Q2 is on.

Comment: But in class A the current never goes to 0A except the clipping when the amplifier is overdriven.

Comment: I use an approximate picture  of working principle to understand in general. If I'll include all additional factors it may be unclear for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to show you two extreme cases (when clipping).

For the **Positive half of a sinusoidal swing**:

[image]

And for **Negative half of a sinusoidal swing**:

[image]

This two cases should help you understand what is going on in the amplifier.

Because in the normal operation we have "slightly" similar situation.

For example:

For the Positive half, \$Q_1\$ reduce his \$I_{C1}\$ current (just a bit), hence \$Q_2\$ must increase his \$I_{C2}\$ current.

But this reduction in \$Q_1\$ current decreases the \$Q_5\$ base current also.

And all this means that the \$I_{C5}\$ collector current is decreasing also.

Hence, the voltage at \$Q_{12}\$ collector increases. 
The larger part of a \$Q_{12}\$ collector current (\$I_{C12}\$)can now flow into the \$Q_7\$ base. So, \$Q_7\$ and \$Q_9\$ conduct more current. And the load current increases.

I hope this helps you. Because my English vocabulary is limited.

Comment: How the current (first picture) can at Q4 collector move to Q3 collector if there is no wire between Q4 collector and Q3 collector?

Comment: Q3 collector current discharge C3 and CbeQ5 to "quickly" Turn-OFF Q5. And this is why I have drawn this current.

Comment: But how Q3 can be on if Q1 is off? Q4-Q3 is current mirror and if Q4 on then Q3 also must be on

Comment: You Answered Your Own Question. Q4-Q3 is a current mirror and if Q4 ON then Q3 also must be ON. Q3 Vbe = Q4 Vbe. Q3 is ON and is in the saturation region.

Comment: i. e. if there is no current through Q1 collector-emitter then Q3 can be on without any collector current because of Q4 on state?

Comment: Its all depend on your definition. Q3 will discharge C3 and Q5 Cbe and after some time Ic3 = 0A but the Vbe3 is still equal to 0.6V.

Comment: If you have any further questions about this topic, do not hesitate to ask me.

Comment: Can I manually find using equations (without simulation) voltages on Q1 emitter and Q12 collector if I know the current that was set through R6? And can I admit in that calculations that Q1 and Q2 bases are at zero voltage?

Comment: Yes, you can find DC bias point by simply assuming that Vin = 0V. Additional because you have C2 capacitor the DC gain is 1V/V. So from there you can find  VE_Q1 = 0V + Vbe1 ≈ 0.6V and Ic1 = Ic2. And the voltage at Q12 collector is equal to Vbe_Q6 - |Vee| ≈ 0.7V - 34V ≈ -33.3V

Comment: I can't fully understand about DC gain equal to 1. If capacitor on DC has infinite impedance, why 22kOhm/infinite = 1?

Comment: But this circuit behaves just like a non-inverting opamp based circuit. Hence the voltage gain is Av = (1 + 22kOhm/infinite ) = 1V/V

Comment: I found that the previous picstures for positive and negative input signal swing shows the DC current that flow through amplifier elements. Is it correct that there is an appropriate swing of input audio signal is imposed on shown currents?

Comment: Yes, The AC signal will modulate the Ic current in "rhythm" of an AC input signal. Here you have the example https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/301617/bjt-input-ac-signal-amplitude/301642#301642

Comment: And in the small-signal analysis, we separately analysis this AC component. Ignoring the DC component. We can do this thanks to the superposition theorem

Comment: Is it complex to draw two additional pictures that show how  the input audio signal will flow through circuit from input to load? Or it's equal to what I draw at the top of post with orange/gray lines?

Comment: The signal will flow for the input into the Q1 base. Next from Q1 collector into the Q6 base and then through Q7 and Q8 for positive swing and through Q10 and Q11 for the negative swing. But this has always nothing to do with how the real current is flowing. Because for example, the output current is coming from PSU. Just as I have drawn in my answer.