# BJT ce amp with current source ac signal behaviour

Tags: amplifier, bjt, current-source

I have the next schematic:

[image]

I want to understand how the AC signal behaves on "Probe2" where the current source is used. When there is no input signal applied only the DC component of current on "Probe2" is presented and there is no output AC current. But what it would be if the input signal applied? Then the DC on "Probe2" must be constant and on positive input signal swing the additional positive AC must be added to DC to build result current level. For negative input signal swing the AC component at "Probe2" must be substracted from DC to form the result current value. And in both previous situations "extra" positive/negative AC must go to load - R5. It's all as I imaging the process of schematic working. Corrent me if I wrong. And what it would be if the load resistor R5 will be removed? The "extra" AC that added/substracted from DC will not have the path to go, where it will be sinked?

[image]

To clarify the question full power amplifier schematic added for help how to understand behaviour of DC + AC on "Probe2".

Comment: I see an issue with this circuit. The DC (bias) voltage at point "Probe2" is tricky to get right. Ideally you want the DC voltage there to be around 5 or 6 V. **But** you basically have two current sources (Ic_Q2 and Ic_Q1) there "fighting" each other. Without some DC feedback it will be impossible to get a predictable DC voltage at "Probe2" and when that voltage is too high or too low Q1 or Q2 will be in saturation and that will lower the gain. The simplest solution is to replace Q2 with a resistor.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yes, the circuit is only a sample and will form two current sources in series, but I need only to understand how the AC current will influence the total current generated by Q2-Q3 current source as I wrote in question. How the DC and AC currents combines together when the current source is used. Is it so (in approximation) as I wrote in my question or it's not?

Comment: How is it useful to discuss the behavior of a circuit that works in a "wrong" way? It is like discussing the mileage (liters/km) of a car **in reverse**. Pointless because no one uses a car like that for any significant distance. In the 2nd circuit there is feedback so you cannot compare the two.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Ok, I fully agree with you. I add the full power amplifier to clarify the application of the first schematic. I need as in first understand how the DC + AC behaves on "Probe2" for positive and negative input signal swing.

Comment: I see a first circuit, which I assume you created, and a second circuit that is quite something else (still not entirely well designed, but at least complete.) The first circuit has nothing whatever to do with the second one, unless you can clarify exactly how it does. And since the first circuit is probably cobbled up from a misunderstanding, it's probably not possible to tell you how one of them relates to the other. At least, I don't see how your questions in the first case bear on understanding anything in the second case.

Comment: @jonk I only need to understand how signal AC component combines with DC on "Probe2". How the constant current source on Q3-Q4 influence the ac signal part on "Probe2"? I tried to recreate that on simple schematic with 3 BJT's and now see that it's not so what it must be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circuit won't work properly.

The bias resistors R3 and R4 set 1.64 volts on Q1's base. This in turn *should* define the collector current. Because the emitter voltage is 0.7 volts lower at 0.94 volts, the current through the emitter should be 0.94 volts / 100 ohms or 9.4 mA.

This should, within a few percent, equal the collector current but your current mirror is only able to supply about 5.8 mA so there is a disparity in your circuit and Q1 will be trying to drag 9.4 mA from a 5.8 mA source.

Short story is heavy signal distortion and asymmetry in the output. Try simulating it and see. I know you have multisim and can use it because you did so in your previous question.

When you get it working you will see that R5 does indeed affect the AC signal gain and it becomes quite high when it is open circuit.

Comment: In simulation I see that circuit work but without much useful meaning. If I set R5=10k instead 1k the oscilloscope shows more gain. It seems the circuit really performs the fighting of 2 current sources (as other commenter says). I build that circuit to create simple imitation of power amplifier part - voltage gain stage with current source as a load. And this need me to understand how the DC + AC bevahes on output "Probe2" in projection to power amplifier working principle. And I need help with it as I wrote in my question.

Comment: I add the full power amplifier to clarify the application of the first schematic.

Comment: Changing the circuit is just wasting my time.

Comment: I don't change circuit totally - the concept is same. I need only to understand how AC current on "Probe2" combines with DC current on "Probe2" and forms a total value. Will be it so as I wrote or not or something else?

Answer (score 0):

In your second schematic, and in relation to the "probe 2" there, it's not too much to think about.

There is a DC current flowing through the two diodes in series. This current sets up a voltage across the diodes. This summed voltage difference across the two diodes forms something not unlike a "battery" that provides just enough voltage difference between the two bases of your output transistors so that the cross-over distortion is reduced.

The AC signal is applied to \$Q_5\$. It's collector voltage varies based upon the supplied base current (which arrives via the diff-amp of \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$.) When its collector voltage moves up, the base voltage of the diode-pair "battery" moves up, too. When its collector voltage moves down, the base voltage of the diode-pair also moves down. Either way, the two bases of the output BJTs move in lock-step with these changes.

Your probe 2 is just at the top of this diode-pair "battery." So it moves in lock-step, as well, except it is two diode drops above the collector voltage of \$Q_5\$.

Feedback via \$R_7\$ makes sure that the current that feeds \$Q_5\$, causes the collector voltage of \$Q_5\$ to be just what is needed so that the output voltage reflects the input (plus gain.)

Comment: It's all good but it's for voltage. I'm trying to create a concept in mind how the AC + DC "current" on Probe 2 will behave, not voltage.

Comment: @MaxMil Read once again what I have written here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/336130/power-amplifier-input-source-current-path Which part you do not understand?

Comment: @MaxMil In an almost ideal world the current would not vary at all. There is a current mirror in your own first schematic, so I know you "kind of" know this. If you had the "perfect world" then the current would vary by exactly just the right amount needed to feed the driver BJT base currents plus a fixed steady invariant current for the series diodes (assuming constant temps.) I'm sure you have a question in your mind. I get that. But I don't exactly follow why you have it and what you are struggling over.