# What indicates a capacitor being charged or discharge in a circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

I am having troubles determining when a capacitor is being charged or being discharged, never understood the concept when a capacitor is under going that process besides the fact when a Source is connected to a cap it will charged to said source, and once removed it will start discharging.

I am talking about more complicated circuit such as ones below.

**Circuit Diagram: being questioned**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGClc4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Positive Cycle Analysis :**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2famFOk.png)</sup>

**Negative Cycle analysis**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8wWMv.png)</sup>

I understand the positive cycle is charging the capacitor through R1, and R2, however for the negative Cycle I have no idea what that capacitor is doing? I am not even sure if this analysis is right, but this is the only thing that makes sense to me.

This is suppose to be a rectifier circuit, where it charges on every cycle I guess? So maybe the negative cycle is charging the cap as well, but when is it being discharge?

I guess what I am trying to ask if that if a cap is charging or discharging How do one find the path it takes to be charged/discharge.

EDIT: With a bit more thinking I figured the capacitor is both charging and discharging in the same cycle both postive and negative. I am still confused on which path current takes for discharging, and charging. For example if you look at the positive cycle and its discharging, is the current flow opposite and if so does that make the diode forward bias again thus changing the topology of the circuit?

Comment: Did it charge up past 1V on the positive cycle?

Comment: it doesnt charge past 1V?, not sure if I have the models right but in actuality the circuit is working fine. Just trying to understand whats going on with the cap as I need to know how the cap is discharging and discharging to improve attack and delay on - oncoming waveforms

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287394/ac-circuit-having-only-capacitor/287475#287475  this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/310471/help-understanging-ac-signal-connected-to-a-charged-capacitor-coupling-capacito/310496#310496

Comment: I see, were my models correct?

Comment: Yes, for the positive cycle, the opamp cannot "close the negative feedback loop" because of the D1 diode is in reverse bias. Let us momentarily freeze the input signal. Now suppose we allow the input signal to rise.

Comment: Since the (-) terminal of the op-amp does not draw any significant current. We can see, even without calculating values, that the (-) input will now be positive. The op-amp will now amplify this voltage to produce a negative-going output (inverting input). And this will further reverse biased the D1 diode. As the output starts increasing in the negative direction and will go all the way to its negative saturation limit (negative supply voltage). So for a positive cycle, we can ignore opamp.

Comment: For the negative cycle, the voltage at  (-) input will now be negative. So the output will go into the positive direction and this will forward biased the D1 diode and closed the negative feedback loop. Op-amp now can bring the voltage at (-)input the level of a (+) voltage. https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/two-simple-questions-but-im-troubled-by-them.64696/#post-444315

Comment: Oh man thank you that was a good read. The only thing I am confused at is, let me know if I am wrong. Lets say for the positive cycle the capacitor is charging up as Vin goes towards +Vp, now when it goes back towards 0 it discharges will this forward bias the diode and change the topology of the circuit? and how does current flow when a capacitor is discharging in both cases?

Comment: For positive cycle at the input diode will never conduct any current. So you can remove the opamp from the circuit and analysis simple RC circuit.  As for the capacitor current. Charging--> current into (enters the capacitor plates) capacitor and voltage rise across the capacitor. Discharging ---> current leaves the capacitor plates and voltage drops.

Comment: I see, I would assume sense when discharging the capacitor it shifts the flow of the current through the circuit so I assumed that the flow of the op amp will now be forwarding biasing the diode. Either way the capacitor is being discharged and charged through the resistors of R1 and R2 right?

Comment: @G36, please formulate a final answer and post it.

Comment: I will! Its kinda late here so tomorrow morning for sure, and I am still kinda uneasy of the idea of how if the discharging current changes the direction of all the other currents with the circuit its hard to believe the diode isnt biased. Is it when current goes through a cap is charging and when moving out of it its discharging? This is for the positive cycle. I feel a diagram or a picture will put me at ease

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the positive cycle:**

Opamp output voltage is at negative saturation (positive voltage at inverting input). Hence we can remove the opamp from the circuit if we want to analysis the positive cycle.

Addtionolen you should notice that the signal period is:

\$t = \frac{1}{1\textrm{kHz}}=1\textrm{ms} \$

And this time is much less than the **RC** time constant

\$t = RC = 2\textrm{k}\Omega \cdot 470\mu\textrm{F} = 940\textrm{ms}\$

So, **Vin** won't affect the capacitor voltage much. We can say that this voltage is unchanged.

For example, if we have 1V across the capacitor and we set the **Vin** voltage at **0V**

The capacitor will start to discharge with the time constant \$t = RC = 940\textrm{ms} \$.

And the current will flow in this path:

Upper capacitor plate ---> R1--->R2--->gnd--->lower capacitor plate.

And the opamp will don't have any influence in this process. 
Because the D1 diode is reversed biased due to the fact that the voltage at (-) input is positive (0.5V at the beginning of a discharge process) and opamp output at negative situation voltage.

And at the end of a discharging process when the capacitor voltage is almost 0V (after **5*RC**). 
The opamp output will rise up to 0.7V. To forward based the D1 diode and kept the output voltage at 0V.

**For the negative cycle**,

The voltage at (-) input will now be negative. So the output will go into the positive direction and this will further forward biased the D1 diode.

And the capacitor will be quickly charged to this new voltage in the path:

Vcc--->opamp_internal transistor--->D1--->C1-->gnd.

The opamp will also provide a current for R1 and R2 resistors.

But now if you change the input voltage to **-0.5V** we encounter an interesting situation. 
The capacitor voltage is at **+1V** but the input signal is at -0.5V
So, the opamp (-) input we see the positive voltage

**(+1V - (-0.5V))* R1/R1+R2 + (-0.5V) = 1.5V/2 - 0.5V = 0.25V.**

Therefore at this moment of time, the opamp output will go into negative saturation voltage and turn-off the diode.

And our capacitor will begin the discharge process in this path:

Upper capacitor plate--->R2-->R1-->Input signal source--->Gnd--->lower capacitor plate.

And we can find the discharge time

$$t = RC \cdot ln \left(\frac{V_{\infty} - V_{start}}{V_{\infty} - V_{end}} \right)$$

$$t = 940\textrm{ms} \cdot ln \left(\frac{-0.5V-1V}{-0.5V - 0.5V} \right) = 940\textrm{ms} \cdot 0.405 \approx 380\textrm{ms} $$

And once again as discharge process ends the op amps kicks-in into action. 
And ensures that Vout = 0.5V

Comment: Thank you that actually cleared a lot of things up. Just curious is this a type "Upper capacitor plate ---> R1--->R2--->gnd--->lower capacitor plate" For the positive cycle? Should it be R2---->R1 instead?

Comment: Yep, a typo.  It should be  R2--->R1

Comment: okay okay you actually made everything make sense

SO essentially, 

Positive Cycle: Cap is being charged thru R1-R2  discharged thru R2- R1

Negative Cycle: Cap is being charged thru OP AMP->D1 and discharged thru R2 and R1 because when Vin hits back to ~0 the diode becomes reversed bias again

Comment: Can you change the charge time of the cap during the negative cycle as the R2 and R1 doesnt influence it?

Comment: So you want a quick discharge phase during the negative cycle?

Comment: Essentially the application here is to rectify audio signals, I want it to that the cap can track the audio peaks essentially, so be fast enough to charge and discharge fast enough to see the next frequencies.

Comment: Another concern though? During the positive cycle its essentially a Low pass filter so I would need to design in such a way that it doesn't attenuated my viable frequencies (20Hz to 20khz)?

Comment: So you are looking for an envelope detector (googol on it). And normally we are adding discharge resistor in parallel with the capacitor to reduce the decay time.

Comment: Doesn't that alter the charge time as well? I shall!

Just looked at it thats exactly what it is wow

I like that concept however I want the output to be smoothed out, essentially same-thing but smoothed.

Comment: Doesn't that alter the charge time as well? 

I am concerned as well during the positive cycle is becomes a low pass filter in both charging and discharging? and how come when you put a diode it smooths it out? There's a discharging path?? Doesn't adding a resistor also change the charge time for the other cycles as well? as the charging current goes thru R1->R2 oppose to the negative cycle as the charging current doesnt even see the resistors.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out, that cap which I thought would be smoothing it but it doesnt as it discharges, everything makes sense now. I need to add another diode and then add a cap after then a resistor to do the delay and charge time.