# Op amp virtual ground offset problem

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]
I am expecting the blue wave to move up to vcc/2, but it's not the case here. I tried other opamp model with similar result, so it's most likely the problem of the circuit itself. I can't see the wave move through C1 because it's a high pass filter, what value can I set it to to allow the frequency to pass through?

Comment: Simply plot the output at the opamp output before capacitor. And you will see DC-offset

Comment: @G36 I see, you are right

Comment: So where is the problem then?

Comment: @G36 you just solved it.

Comment: A series capacitor at the output will block any DC level you have. If you want to have a DC level, do not use a series coupling capacitor

Comment: @Claudio Avi Chami I see. this cap seems to me also makes the output a lot less too, but I don't get it why it can produce a negative output.

Comment: @Atmega328 it blocks the DC level. The negative and positive values of the sinus are AC, not DC

Comment: The current in the capacitor is related to charging and discharging the capacitor. Look here https://obrazki.elektroda.pl/2434057500_1524909138.png  Where VC1 is a voltage across the capacitor and VR1, is a voltage across the resistor. And what is important here is that during the discharge phase (in green) the current in the resistor R1 flow in the opposite direction than during charging (red). And this is why the voltage across the resistor is negative, despite the fact that the battery produces only positive voltage.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287394/ac-circuit-having-only-capacitor/287475#287475

Comment: @Atmega328 either update your question to reflect your new question or delete this. Nobody is going to produce an answer to your original Q except those desperate to achieve reputation enhancements and that doesn't necessarily enhance this site's reputation. I'm voting to close on that basis.

Comment: @G36 You are sort of right, but in this circuit, we also have another capacitor: C1!!! The results from C1 are similar on each side, and yes, I did change it to 100n, then how come it didn't pass the AC, while C2 passes AC?

Comment: @Andy aka You are absolutely right. I definitely need to revise this question to make it more interesting and educational.

Comment: C2 is not loaded by any resistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am expecting the blue wave to move up to vcc/2, but it's not the case here. I tried other opamp model with similar result, so it's most likely the problem of the circuit itself. I can't see the wave move through C1 because it's a high pass filter, what value can I set it to to allow the frequency to pass through?

c1 doesn't get changed, and c2 turns into a straight piece of wire and the op amp gets changed from a single supply to a dual supply type if you want that dc offset on a single power supply.