# Q: Finding the current through the capacitor

Tags: circuit-analysis

Having a hard time trying to find the current through the capacitor I don't know what method to use.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzFFFZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is how far I have gotten:

Using DC analysis:

1V Positive Cycle input: The op amp is turned off during the positive cycle thus:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvwoyM.png)</sup>

Nodal analysis:

\$ \frac{V_{out}-V_{in}}{4k\Omega}+c\dot V_{out} = 0\$

\$ \frac{V_{out}}{4k\Omega}-\frac{V_{in}}{4k\Omega}+c\dot V_{out} = 0\$

\$ \frac{V_{out}}{4k\Omega}+c\dot V_{out} = \frac{V_{in}}{4k\Omega}\$

Laplace Transform:

\$ \frac{V_{out}(s)}{4k\Omega}+sc V_{out} = \frac{V_{in}(s)}{4k\Omega}\$

\$ V_{out}(s)[\frac{1}{4k\Omega}+s470uF]=\frac{V_{in}(s)}{4k\Omega}\$

\$ \frac{V_{out}(s)}{V_{in}(s)} = \frac{1}{1.88s+1}\$

as S->0

Becomes DC gain of 1
\$ \frac{V_{out}(s)}{V_{in}(s)} = \frac{1}{1.88(0)+1}\$

\$ \frac{V_{out}(s)}{V_{in}(s)} =1\$

Thus Vout = 1V

EDIT: Just to add on to the discussion

[image]

Positive cycle becomes a RC circuit, to be exact a

\$ H(s) = \frac{1}{1.88s+1}\$

You can even predict the output via transfer function

\$ H(jw) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1.88*2*50*\pi)^2+1^2}}\$

\$ H(jw) = 0.008465676V\$

\$ H(jw) = 8.47mV\$ which is exact answer.

However looking at the whole thing positive cycle it doesnt match? Should it be the same thing? As we model? During the positive cycle it should have a behavior of a RC circuit? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you figured out so far? Do you know what the voltage across the capacitor looks like?

Comment: Yeah, Let me put that up there

Comment: Updated it, I just dont understand cause in DC a cap is open so not sure its even possible. I get it cause I used a DC power supply however when I use an AC supply I get the same Vout but cant find how they got the current.

Comment: Maybe what i am asking is how to do analysis this circuit using AC?

Comment: I mean the positive case is easy, I mean when the op amp is going thru a negative cycle

Comment: Yuck, this is ugly.  The diode makes it non-linear, which means Laplace probably doesn't apply unless there's some multiple-interval trick I've forgotten about.

Comment: For AC or DC? In general, the capacitor current is proportional the rate of voltage change across it \$I = C \frac{dV}{dt}\$. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287394/ac-circuit-having-only-capacitor/287475#287475

Comment: Yeah, its pretty ugly and confusing the crap out of me.

Comment: How would one circuit analysis this with a diode then?

Comment: When the diode is ON we replace the diode with a voltage source and resistor (or only voltage source).  And when the diode is OFF diode = open circuit.

Comment: Thats make sense, then how would you go about finding the current through the capacitor then? I am getting stumped by the fact my input is an AC source but however my output is DC so how does one go about finding the voltages and current within this circuit? I Tried using Transfer function/ Frequency response that didnt work, should I try using phasor ?

Comment: But the current will vary with the time. So what "current" you want to calaculate and why ?

Comment: G36 Not sure if you remember but you once helped me with something like this a while back, I took a long break and pretty forgot everything haha. 

Its the same precision rectifier circuit! I just want to know how to analysis  the circuit so I can improve it and predict the output of the system. I am getting confused cause this is technically AC-DC circuit so I just dont know what circuit method to use. Do I make a transfer function? Do I assume the circuit is in DC or AC do I do a frequency response or do I do a phasor of the circuit. I am lost

Comment: For a positive cycle, you have a simple RC circuit. And for a negative one, you have a dinge diode rectifier with the capacitor at the output. http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/01353a.pdf  and this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fn5kHhNRsz0

Comment: Yeah exactly, for the positive I have a RC circuit, but why in simulation it's a DC output and not an attenuated wave form from my input source? Thats whats throwing me off.

Comment: when you say DC output are you looking at the voltage on the capacitor or the current?

Comment: Voltage, sorry if I didn't make myself clear. Essentially I just want to know how to analyze these type of circuit with just nodal, transfer function, or however way to predict the circuits output. I am confused here cause this circuit is a AC- DC circuit so I dont know which method to use to obtain the correct answer.

Comment: "but why in simulation it's a DC output"  Because the RC time constant is much much large than the AC signal period. Do you get it now?

Comment: Yeah, just figured it now, but it doesnt answer this. Ill edit the main question

Comment: @G36 Edit the main question to show where I am stuck at

Comment: Because you are forgetting that during the negative cycle the capacitor is very quickly charged to Vin value. And during the positive cycle, you still have an RC circuit but need to include the initial capacitor voltage and the time constant.

Comment: Ah you're right, totally forgot that the capacitor in the negative cycle is instantly exposed to the input source Through the op amp.

So coming back to the positive cycle (For the second time) the capacitor initial voltage is at now 5V?

Comment: The positive cycle cycle charger the capacitor every 8.47mV? or something

Comment: and how does one find the output voltage during the negative cycle would you use DC or AC analysis for that? The positive cycle was easy due to the fact we could have disregarded the op amp.

Comment: That still doesnt explain the initial voltage output on the positive cycle (first time)

Comment: @Pllsz "That still doesnt explain the initial voltage output on the positive cycle (first time)" You are wrong the response will be exactly the same. If at the beginning of a positive cycle the capacitor voltage is 0V. At the end of this cycle the capacitor voltage will reach 3.38mV for 1V peak at the input and 50Hz.