# Rc ac parallel circuits:-

Tags: circuit-analysis

can someone, simply explain why does the capacitor current leads the resistor current by 90 degree in an rc ac parallel circuits, pls be simple.
I thought about it but found no answer.

Comment: If they’re in parallel, the R and C have the same voltage across them. But current leads voltage through the C, and current is in phase with voltage through the R.

Comment: Try read this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287394/ac-circuit-having-only-capacitor/287475#287475

Comment: Wow i thought about that chu  , but the real questions is  how that happens in a physical sense i Don get it

Comment: Or in simple terms, when the capacitor is fully charged no current is flowing through the capacitor. But when the capacitor is empty the maximum current is flowing through the capacitor. Hence we have a phase shift between the voltage and the current in the capacitor.

Comment: Man i am good at capacitor i love them, but i Don get it!!!

Comment: I Don get how in physical sense does the the current through a capacitor leads the current through the resistor in rc ac parallel circuits!!

Comment: Because in the capacitor for a sine wave excitation the current in the capacitor leads the voltage by 90 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental property of a capacitor is Ic=CdV/dt.

When you apply any sinusoidal voltage and take the derivative, what do you get ?

A cosine current which leads voltage by 90 deg.

Comment: man i don comprehend that i swear i solved a trillion  question , but just cannot get how does a capacitor current leads voltage in a parallel rc ac circuit . 

in a series rc it is obvious that vr leads total voltage and total voltage is already "happening" before it reaches the capacitor  so a percentage of Vt is leading Vc and lagging Vr , we can use phasers to see that .

but in a parallel rc ac circuit nothing makes sense

Comment: YOu can visualize it here http://tinyurl.com/y5cw6y5c