# How current leads by 90° in capacitor while charge on other plate is always opposite, should we not say it lead by 180°

Tags: capacitor

When we start charging the capacitors the charge on the other plate is always opposite & equal then how come we say current lead voltage by 90°, should not we say that it lag/lead by 180°.

Comment: don't think it will answer the question, but think these concepts as follows: 1: capacitor does not allow the voltage across it to change **instantaneously**, so voltage **lags** behind the current. 2: inductors does not allow the current passing through themselves to change **instantaneously**, so current **lags** behind the voltage. Since the current and voltage equations of capacitor and inductor, respectively, are related with a **derivative**, it corresponds to a 90 degrees of shift in complex plane, or phase angle you can say.

Comment: Try to read this answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287394/ac-circuit-having-only-capacitor/287475#287475

Comment: When you 'start charging' it's in the transient region. When a sinusoidal current has been flowing for some time it's in sinusoidal steady state - and this is where phase angle is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your text has a proper physical interpretation.

When a capacitor is charged with sinusoidal current and the potentials of both plates are observed independently against a distant reference point in the space, we really can say that the AC components of the potentials have opposite phase angles or as well one leads another by 180 degrees. But that's not better nor worse than the totally other fact: The sinusoidal charging current of a capacitor leads 90 degrees the voltage between the plates. These two facts have only a common happening environment - a capacitor under charging with sinusoidal current.

Answer (score 2):

In a capacitor, current is the derivative of voltage, which means that current is change rate of voltage. (exactly \$I=C*dU/dt\$)

If you differentiate a sine wave, you get another sine with 90deg phase lag (aka a cosine).

So the 90deg thing has nothing to do with opposite charges.