# Sketching the voltage waveform of a capacitor

Tags: capacitor, waveform, homework

I'm currently learning about capacitors,

**Question:**

[image: Question without Figure]

[image: Figure]

Ignore the fact that it says voltage on the figure, the question reused the waveform of a previous question.

Since I = C(dv/dt), and C = 1 F, i assumed that the waveform of the voltage is the integral of I(t). However drawing the waveform it looks discontinuous, which shouldn't happen. How should i solve the question?

Here is how i tried finding the waveform. I apologize for the crude writing, as it is pretty late right now.

[image: How i tried]

I stopped halfway because i checked if it is already discontinuous through online graphing (GeoGabra), and it is as shown:

[image: Discontinuous voltage waveform]

Comment: Look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287394/ac-circuit-having-only-capacitor/287475#287475 Did it help?

Comment: The diagram is not correct. It does not give current as described in the text, it clearly gives voltage (V).

Comment: Show us the waveform you came up with, along with the equations you used. Show us all of your work.

Comment: @G36 Thank you. I read it through and I still couldn't find the reason why the waveform i came up with was discontinuous.

Comment: @Justme The reason so is because the figure was used for another previous problem. The question just changes the figure from voltage to current in terms of mA.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I have added my work and the waveform i found.

Comment: The voltage cannot be discontinuous.  The energy stored in the electric field of a capacitor is equal to \$1/2Cv^2(t)\$.  Use the graphs you have and remove the discontnuity.

Comment: There will be no discontinuity. From 0s to 1s the capacitor is charging from 0V to 25mV and from 1s to 2s capacitor is sill charging and the voltage will rise from 25mV to 50mV (but the charging current will drop from 50mA to 0A). And again from 2s to 3s the capacitor starts the charging phase and at t = 3s the Vc = 75mV. And from 4s the capacitor will be charge at constant rate Vc = 50mV per second.

Comment: @G36 Would the curve of the charge be the same as the charging curve from the link you gave me? Or the chargimg curve from the waveform i found?

Comment: @Myadra22  Because from time = 0s to t = 3s the current is constantly changing in a linear fashion the voltage waveform across the cap will by looking like you have found but there will be no discontinuity in the waveform.

Comment: This is what I 'v get using Math software  https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUElV.png

Comment: Oh, so the numbers and graph i got was correct. Thank you for helping.