# In parallel RC circuits, why does a phase difference between the net current and resistive current exist?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, current, resistors

In an RC circuit, I was asked to find the phase difference between \$I\$ and \$I_1\$, as the branch via which \$I_1\$ is flowing is resistive, I felt it would be 0 , but my book says it's 53. I have looked at answers online, but this doesn't make conceptual sense to me.

The circuit:

[image: schematic]

Comment: Hint: Compute the parallel impedance of the resistor and capacitor -- it'll be a complex number.

Comment: At what frequency? Phase of I must always be 0 ...

Comment: sorry for not mentioning that, 100=w

Comment: @ErikR, How would I do that?How would I find the phase difference to add them?

Comment: Calculate voltage accross R and C. Then currents. Ok. Perhaps frequency not useful.

Comment: Ok. Frequency not useful

Comment: The phase difference exists because you have a capacitor in your circuit.  And when a capacitor is "fully charged" (at the peak value of a Vin) no current is flowing through the capacitor. But when a capacitor is "empty" (when Vin is crossing 0V ) the maximum current is flowing.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287394/ac-circuit-having-only-capacitor/287475#287475

Answer (score 1):

The "current generator" (in the simulator) has (generally) a phase = 0, because we can't know its "voltage".
But the voltage phase across components (R paralleled C as pointed out by @ErikR) or the generator is not.
So, calculate the voltage and then the current through the resistor.

[image: calculations]

Answer (score 0):

Impedance of the capacitor is -j3 Ω. Since voltage across resistor and capacitor is same, current I is divided into \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$. You can see how using current divider method in your book which follows KVL and KCL.
$$ I_1 = I \frac {-j3} {4- j3} $$
Similarly  $$ I_2 = I \frac {4} {4- j3} $$
Using phasor equations, you can then calculate \$\angle{ (I/I_1)} \$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the phase difference between the source current and resistor current is given by:

$$\Delta:=\left|\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{source}}\right)-\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{R}}\right)\right|\tag1$$

Using (the complex) Ohm's law and well-kown rules for the \$\arg\$ function, we can see that:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\Delta&=\left|\arg\left(\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{source}}}{\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}}\right)-\arg\left(\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{R}}}{\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{R}}}\right)\right|\\
\\
&=\left|\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{source}}\right)-\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)-\left(\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{R}}\right)-\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{R}}\right)\right)\right|\\
\\
&=\left|\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{source}}\right)-\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)-\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{R}}\right)+\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{R}}\right)\right|\\
\\
&=\left|\underbrace{\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{source}}\right)-\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{R}}\right)}_{=\space0}+\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{R}}\right)-\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)\right|\\
\\
&=\left|\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{R}}\right)-\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)\right|
\end{split}\tag2
\end{equation}

We can see that \$\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{source}}\right)-\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{R}}\right)=0\$ because the voltages are parallel so they have the same phase.

So, we get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\Delta&=\left|\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{R}}\right)-\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)\right|\\
\\
&=\left|\underbrace{\arg\left(\text{R}\right)}_{=\space0}-\arg\left(\text{R}\space\text{||}\space\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\right)\right|\\
\\
&=\left|-\arg\left(\frac{\text{R}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}{\text{R}+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}\right)\right|\\
\\
&=\left|-\arg\left(\frac{\text{R}}{1+\text{j}\omega\text{CR}}\right)\right|\\
\\
&=\left|-\left(\underbrace{\arg\left(\text{R}\right)}_{=\space0}-\arg\left(1+\text{j}\omega\text{CR}\right)\right)\right|\\
\\
&=\left|\arg\left(1+\text{j}\omega\text{CR}\right)\right|\\
\\
&=\left|\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{CR}}{1}\right)\right|\\
\\
&=\left|\arctan\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)\right|\\
\\
&=\arctan\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)
\end{split}\tag3
\end{equation}

Where \$\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\alpha\cdot\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\$.

---

Using your values we can see that:

$$\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}=3\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\omega\text{C}=\frac{1}{3}\tag4$$

So:

$$\Delta=\left|\arctan\left(\frac{1}{3}\cdot4\right)\right|=\arctan\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\approx0.927\space\text{rad}\approx53.13^\circ\tag5$$